# Java: GroupSequenceProvider for Validation, object is null in getValidationGroups method

Tags: spring, hibernate, validation, spring-mvc, spring-boot

This is what I am trying to achieve:
I have an update request object and user is allowed to do Partial Updates. But I want to validate the field only if it is in the request body. Otherwise, it is OK to be null. To achieve this, I am using GroupSequenceProvider to let the Validator know what groups to validate. What am I doing wrong here? If there is a blunder, how do I fix it?

Documentation: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.1/reference/en-US/html/chapter-groups.html#example-implementing-using-default-group-sequence-provider

```
@GroupSequenceProvider(UpdateUserRegistrationGroupSequenceProvider.class)
public class UpdateUserRegistrationRequestV1 {

@NotBlank(groups = {EmailExistsInRequest.class})
@Email(groups = {EmailExistsInRequest.class})
@SafeHtml(whitelistType = SafeHtml.WhiteListType.NONE, groups = {EmailExistsInRequest.class})
private String email;

@NotNull(groups = {PasswordExistsInRequest.class})
@Size(min = 8, max = 255, groups = {PasswordExistsInRequest.class})
private String password;

@NotNull(groups = {FirstNameExistsInRequest.class})
@Size(max = 255, groups = {FirstNameExistsInRequest.class})
@SafeHtml(whitelistType = SafeHtml.WhiteListType.NONE, groups = {FirstNameExistsInRequest.class})
private String firstName;

// THERE ARE GETTERS AND SETTERS BELOW
}
```

Group Sequence Provider Code:

```
public class UpdateUserRegistrationGroupSequenceProvider implements DefaultGroupSequenceProvider<UpdateUserRegistrationRequestV1> {

public interface EmailExistsInRequest {}

public interface PasswordExistsInRequest {}

public interface FirstNameExistsInRequest {}

@Override
public List<Class<?>> getValidationGroups(UpdateUserRegistrationRequestV1 updateUserRegistrationRequestV1) {
    List<Class<?>> defaultGroupSequence = new ArrayList<Class<?>>();
    defaultGroupSequence.add(Default.class);
    defaultGroupSequence.add(UpdateUserRegistrationRequestV1.class);

    if(StringUtils.hasText(updateUserRegistrationRequestV1.getEmail())) {
        defaultGroupSequence.add(EmailExistsInRequest.class);
    }

    if(StringUtils.hasText(updateUserRegistrationRequestV1.getPassword())) {
        defaultGroupSequence.add(PasswordExistsInRequest.class);
    }

    if(StringUtils.hasText(updateUserRegistrationRequestV1.getFirstName())) {
        defaultGroupSequence.add(FirstNameExistsInRequest.class);
    }

    return defaultGroupSequence;
}
}
```

I am using Spring MVC, so this is how my controller method looks,

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/{userId}", method = RequestMethod.PUT, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
public void updateUser(@PathVariable("userId") Long userId,
                       @RequestBody @Valid UpdateUserRegistrationRequestV1 request) {

    logger.info("Received update request = " + request + " for userId = " + userId);

    registrationService.updateUser(userId, conversionService.convert(request, User.class));
}
```

Now the problem is, the parameter "updateUserRegistrationRequestV1" in the UpdateUserRegistrationGroupSequenceProvider.getValidationGroups method is null. This is the request object that I am sending in the request body and I am sending email field with it.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I am having same isssue? Do you get any solution for this?

Comment: Could you solve this issue? I am having the same problem.

Comment: Documentation of getValidationGroups says:This value can be {@code null} in case this method was called as part of* {@linkplain javax.validation.Validator#validateValue(Class, String, Object, Class[]) Validator#validateValue}.

Answer (score 0):

I too went through the same issue ,and  hopefully solved it

You just have to check the object is null and put all your conditions inside it.

```
public List<Class<?>> getValidationGroups(Employee object) {
        List<Class<?>> sequence = new ArrayList<>();
        //first check if the object is null
        if(object != null ){
             if (!object.isDraft()) {
                    sequence.add(Second.class);
                }
        }


        // Apply all validation rules from default group
        sequence.add(Employee.class);

        return sequence;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just like Mysterious_Anny answer say, if object is null ,only one thing you should do is adding target object class in sequence and return.
otherwise implement your custom group validation logic and return